# Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client- even after return()

Tags: node.js, api, nodes

i have 4 services inline to check for different things.. After that, I return a JSON Response. return() should have completed the execution.

```
   userService.verifyUsername(username,(err,result)=>{
        if(result){
            errors.username = username+" is already registered";
            return res.status(200).json({status:0,code:1,errors});
        }
    });

    userService.verifiEmail(emailId,(err,result)=>{
        if(result){
            errors.email = emailId+" is already registered";
            return res.status(200).json({status:0,code:1,errors});
        }
    });

    userService.verifyMobile(mobileNo,(err,result)=>{
        if(result){
            errors.mobileNo = mobileNo+" is already registered";
            return res.status(200).json({status:0,code:1,errors});
        }
    });

    userService.verifyRefferalId(refferalId,(err,result)=>{
        if(err){
            errors.refId=" referral id is invalid";
            return res.status(200).json({status:0,code:1,errors})
        }
    });
```

Error
Error [ERR_HTTP_HEADERS_SENT]: Cannot set headers after they are sent to the client
at new NodeError (node:internal/errors:371:5)
at ServerResponse.setHeader (node:_http_outgoing:576:11)

Comment: Show code where you use them

Comment: @Anatoly. What i  was doing was . i was checking against different services. If  there was only one error.. if was fine. In case of  more than one error it was calling return, causing this error.. Fixed .. Thanks anyway

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.